# How can i get IP and PORT from payload unsigned char buf?

Tags: c++, c, char, unsigned, payload

I have unsigned char buf:

IP is at position 197 and port is at position 205. 
How can i get correct IP and PORT from this unsigned char buf ?

I tried some number converting but had no luck :(

Any help or hint appreciated.

Comment: What 'number converting' have you tried? Post some code.

Comment: Have you tried: port = buf[196];` ?

Comment: Have you tried getpeername()? Or recvfrom()?

Comment: I tried hex to dec, hex to binary, hex to text ... I tried port = buf[196] i got 8 in that position.

Comment: How do i try getpeername() or recvfrom() ?

Comment: Are you sure the port is not coded as a 2-byte integer in your buffer?

Comment: If it is then int number = buf[204] | buf[205] << 8; returns 13568 which could be correct, but i suspect IP is still wrong.

Comment: The given unsigned char buffer was generated using command: msfpayload windows/shell/reverse_tcp LHOST=... LPORT=... C where i now do not know LHOST and LPORT, ijust know the positions of them in the buffer. Now i have to get them back. It is a mystery to be solved ;)

Answer (score 1):

I assume, IP starts at 197th position and it occupies 4 places in array(1 for each octant) and 1 place for port. In C/C++ 197th position should be accessed with index 196. So, you can access the 4 octants of IP and port address by following way,

```
short int octants[] ={buf[196],buf[197],buf[198],buf[199]} ;
short int portId = buf[204] ;
```

Comment: See my edited post, i tried with simple program, but it is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Ok i found the solution, thanks for the kick in the right direction guys :)

The code which outputs correct result is:

```
printf("IP: %d.%d.%d.%d", buf[197], buf[198], buf[199], buf[200]);

int port = 0;                           // Start with zero
port |= buf[204] & 0xFF;                // Assign first byte to port using bitwise or.
port <<= 8;                             // Shift the bits left by 8 (so the byte from before is on the correct position)
port |= buf[205] & 0xFF;

printf(" Port: %d", port);
```

And the result is: IP: 8.8.8.8 Port: 53